# No Country Redirect + Predictive search ( search suggestions) in Chrome omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, search, redirection, search-engines, omnibox

As I can see predictive search works well with default google search engine.

As [described here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/e27h1dzXTUE), I change search engine to NCR mode:

`http://www.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s`

But not predictive search stops works..
I thought, that phrase in search engine `google:acceptedSuggestion` should be responsible for predictive list in omnibox.. but it isn't.

How to setup NCR with predictive search?